# What is Big O of a loop with square root inside?

Tags: algorithms, big-o-notation

Knowing that `O(n^2) > O(nlogn) > O(n) > O(sqrt(n)) > O(logn) > O(1)` and having below python code:

```
import math

def f1(n=9):
    return math.sqrt(n)

def f2(n=10):
    return [math.sqrt(i) for i in range(n)]
```

- Am I correct to infer that **O(f1(n)) = O(1)**
- Am I correct to infer that **O(f1(n)) = O(n)**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815339/time-complexity-of-math-sqrt-java?lq=1
this question answers your question: to calculate the root of $n$, takes $O(log(n))$ time and **not** $O(1)$.

Comment: Python-specific questions are off topic here. As always, it depends on the computation model. In the word RAM model, any function which takes a constant number of words and returns a constant number of words is assumed to be $O(1)$, so (say) square root of a binary64 floating point number takes constant time.

Comment: @Pseudonym The reason that I'm asking is because I'm confused, and I have right to be confused because looking at your and nirshahar comments I see two different answers for sqrt(n).

Comment: It depends on what you do with it: in a theoretical sense it would be $O(log(n))$. In a practical sense, unless you compute the square root of some immensely large number - you _could_ consider it $O(1)$